# Change background color for page control

Tags: ios, tvos, apple-tv

Is there any way to change background color of page control in **tvOS**?

**NOTE**: i want to set background color as clear color

I have try the below code, but it is not working in **tvOS**.

```
var pageControl : UIPageControl!
pageControl = UIPageControl(frame: CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.height - 200, self.view.frame.width, 50))
pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 0.70)
pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
pageControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
pageControl.opaque = false
pageControl.numberOfPages = 10
pageControl.currentPage = 0
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This transparent background is a subview in UIPageControl of type UIVisualEffectView. You could remove it like this:

```swift
for subview in pageControl.subviews {
  if subview.isKindOfClass(UIVisualEffectView) {
    subview.removeFromSuperview()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. Working perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

The fix Alexander mentioned didn't work for me when too many pages had to be displayed. I would rather set the effect to nil:

```
for subview in pageControl.subviews {
    guard let effectView = subview as? UIVisualEffectView else { continue }
    effectView.effect = nil
}
```

Comment: yes! this worked for me, `removeFromSuperView()` makes some of the dots disappears in the next setting `numberOfPages`.

Answer (score 0):

@alexander-johmann above has a solution (though I'd like to find another way).

Ideally it would be better to be able to set the actual background color.  This solution doesn't really do that; it removes elements of the UIPageControl to get the 'effect' of providing a clear background without actually doing so.

Here is an objective-c version of the same code:

```
for (UIView *subview in pageControl.subviews) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIVisualEffectView class]] == YES) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```